# Entity Inheritance in DDD

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I am trying to design a Domain Model of an E-Commerce system using DDD guidelines. I have a situation where I have 2 different types of Products. One product is "Item" and the other product is "Package" (Group/Bundle of Items). My domain model so far looks like this

```
public abstract class Product : IAggregateRoot
{
    public string ProductId { get; protected set; }

    // Many to Many relationship between Item and Package
    protected List<ItemPackageRelationship> ItemPackages => new List<ItemPackageRelationship>();

    protected List<Image> Images => new List<Image>();

    // Other properties shared between Item and Package
}

public class Item : Product
{
    // All properties and methods specific to Item

    public void SetImages(List<string> images)
    {
       // Set images for Item has its own business logic

       // Example: number of allowed images, size of image etc
    }
}

public class Package : Product
{
   // All properties and method related to package

    public void SetImages(List<string> images)
    {
       // Set images for Package has its own business logic

       // Exampe: number of allowed images, size of image etc
    }
}
```

All the behavior is defined inside Item and Package class and Product class just has shared properties. Initially I was thinking to create 2 complete separate Aggregate roots (Item and Package) and no Product entity. The only reason I need Product is because of the Unique ProductId in the system. And all the relationship with other entities (like Images) needs to based on ProductId.

I am not 100% confident what I am designing is correct and need some input here. Creating a Base entity just to share some properties is against any principle of DDD? Is there anything else you guys would suggest to improve the design of my Domain Model?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: An EF class model isn't a domain model. It's part of a data access layer and it should be designed to perform that task as smoothly as possible. Realizing this should help you set the right priorities. For the rest this is rather opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

I think inheritence of entities should be driven by behavior, not by properties.
In other words you should look at other busines code, not at entities itself. If you see relatively many places which should operate with an `Item` and with a `Package` in the same manner when iheritence can be used (but is not strictly necessary). Inheritence is not reasonable if the single reason is sharing an unique identifier.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. So the fact is both Item and Package (bundle of item) are the Product that we sell. Both are somewhat similar in terms of attributes and behavior. I know I should not be thinking about database structure when designing my Domain Model but I can't ignore the fact that they both needs to go into same product table. So in that case is it OK to have Items and Package (2 aggregate roots) derived from a abstract class (i.e Product)?

Comment: Use same table or not is an impletentation detail, it should not impact design of domain! Think about logic and behavior. If there is a lot of logic that is the generic for Items and Packages you can use inheritance (but you can use interface too if logic resides outside of entities). Another approach: you can start without inheritence, if in some point of time you noticed what you writing a lot of duplicate code for Package and for Item you can refactor to inheritence.

Comment: Interface sounds like a good idea to me. Now like I mentioned that because both Item and Package are Products, they have some shared properties... Lets say Weight, Price etc... For Item Weight is calculated based on the Item Weight but for Package, it's SUM of all the weights in that Package (this is just one example, there are like 6-8 shared properties between Item and Package with different implementation). I also tried designing my model using Product entity and ProductType (Item or Package). But I ended up with lots of IF checks (based on the type I return the values).

Comment: Now if I use Interface, an create 2 Aggregates (Items and Package), I would be have some shared Value Objects (ProductImage, ProductLocation etc).You think it's ok to have shared value objects between aggregates in this case?

Comment: I can't give a sensible answer because I don't know your domain, requirements to value objects and logic around it. But sharing value objects is not a bad idea itself. I can't say anything against it.

Comment: I have the same conclusion. I had the same situation I used a common data structure in two entities but I got different method names and slightly diferent methods. Moving the code into a common abstract ancestor would have meant LSP violation. So I rather used composition and moved the relavant part of the code into a VO. The rest of the code in the entities is just changing a property having the same VO type, maybe 10 lines of common code, so I rather copied that part instead of having a common ancestor. In certain situations the DRY principle can be violated when we are talking about DDD.

Comment: Note that the same code saves this common VO structure into the same database tables along with the entity id, so it can be decided which entity the VO belongs too. I spare a lot of common code with this database structure without writing abstract code where I inject the table name to the SQL etc.